# Expectation of function of random variable?

Tags: probability-distributions

How to calculate the expectation of function of random variable without using probability density function? Note:- only cumulative distribution function is available.
For example $E[g(X)]$=? where X is  nonnegative r.v. with CDF $F_{X}(x)$.

Comment: If $X$ is a non-negative random variable, then $\int_0^{+\infty}(1-F_X(t))dt=E X$ (use Fubini's theorem).

Comment: What do we know about $g$? Are there other assumptions than measurable?

Comment: g(X) can be any function linear of exponential no further assumptions.

Comment: Just for trivia, the rule you would use is called the "law of unconscious statistician", as you don't actually know the distribution of $g$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $X\geqslant0$ almost surely and if $g$ is regular,
$$
\mathrm E(g(X))=g(0)+\int_0^{+\infty}g'(x)\cdot(1-F_X(x))\cdot\mathrm dx.
$$
**Proof:** integrate with respect to $\mathrm P$ both sides of the almost sure relation
$$
g(X)=g(0)+\int_0^{+\infty}g'(x)\cdot[x\lt X]\cdot\mathrm dx,
$$
where $[\ \ ]$ denotes [Iverson bracket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket).

Comment: You omitted g'(x) in the second integral. I like it, it's a very nice generalisation of the equality mentioned by @DavideGiraudo in the first comment below the question.

Comment: @savick01: Yes, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to hazard a guess about what the original poster might mean.  Suppose wone knows the probability density function of $X$ but not of $g(X)$.  My *guess* is that it is the latter that is not to be used.  In that case, one can write
$$
\mathbb{E}(g(X)) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)f(x)\;dx
$$
where $f$ is the probability density function of $f$.  In other words, one doesn't need to find the probability density function of $g(X)$.

Comment: I am also not interested in finding the PDF of g(X). The question is How we can find the $E[g(X)]$ without using $f(x)$. Whereas we are having CDF of X i.e. $F_{X}(x)$.

Answer (score -1):

At least formally, the probability density function is $f(X) = dF/dX$, so

> $ E[g(X)] = \int dX f(X) g(X) = \int dX g(X) dF/dX = Fg(X_f) - Fg(X_i) - \int dX F(X) dg/dX $.

So if $g(X)$ is differentiable, and $g$ is finite at the endpoints of the domain of $X$ ($X_f$ and $X_i$), then you can try to evaluate the integral above.

Comment: Please: Don't use the capital $X$ to refer to two different things on the same line.  First you wrote $E[g(X)]$, where $X$ is a random variable, then you used the same capital $X$ as the variable of integration.