# How to calculate the mathematical expectation of a function?

Tags: probability-distributions

Suppose that $T$ is a random variable, $F(T)$ the function of random variables. How can I compute the expectation of a function of random variables if the probability density function (PDF) $g(t)$ for $T$ is given?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician

Comment: Similar to your previous question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4361027)

Comment: Ths @311411 and Jean Marie. I get it.

Answer (score 0):

For instance, suppose $T\sim g(t),\;\,$ $\bar{T}=\int_{0}^{\infty}t \cdot g(t)dt$, and $f(t)= T^2$.

How to compute the $E[f(t)]$?

Answer: $\;\;E[{f(t)}]=\int_{0}^{\infty}f(t)g(t)dt$

Comment: No : see the answer of Did [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/92096)